# How do I download a form table in CSV or Excel format?

Tags: 8, forms

I have a form whose class extends `FormBase`. The form has a table that gets populated with information.

Basically I'm trying to download the table into a CSV or Excel file. I've seen some old posts for Drupal 6 but I haven't found anything for Drupal 8.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363) module. Here is a quote from that page:

> ... built of the idea of using SQL to get data out of a database and use XHTML and CSS to format it into web reports.

Here is another quote from [Reasons for considering Forena](https://www.drupal.org/node/2358629), related to the "CSV" in the question here:

> Reports created by Forena ... can be saved (exported) as PDF documents with embedded graphs. Other supported formats for saving a report are **CSV**, XLS, DOC, HTML, etc.

So if you'd install Forena in your site, then these are the steps for creating such CSV files are:

- a custom **SQL query** (where you have the full power of SQL at your fingertips, and various extra features related to it provided by Forena, such as using report parameters, conditional SQL, etc).
- a custom **report** (either by an admin, or by just any regular user who is either familiar with creating what is called 'FRX files', or otherwise using the WYSIWYG report editor).
- saving the report in (eg) CSV format, using one of the typical hyperlinks to do so in a report.

For an **online demo** (prior to installing/testing Forena), checkout these links:

- [Reporting samples](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/samples), about data stored in some SQLite database, and including things like drill down reports, creating charts (using the [PHP SVG Graph library](http://www.goat1000.com/svggraph.php)), etc.
- [Forena Documentation](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help), which you also get in your own site after installing the module).

Disclosure: I'm a **co**-maintainer of this module,
I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).